# Size of Symfony2 project too big when using Composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php

First I downloaded Symfony2 framework (Standard Edition) from the official website and after installing it, the whole Symfony project had **~16MB** in total.
After that, I wanted to start another Symfony2 project using Composer and `create-project` command. After installing, that application had **~130MB**! 
There is huge size difference between those two projects.
I suppose I downloaded some additional bundles when I used Composer, but the difference in size of more than 100MB seems to much.
I checked both projects and they have the same directory structure (i.e. I didn't find some additional directory in the bigger project).
So, why is there such a big difference and what I did wrong to have such a huge project when  I used Composer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might be that you have git clones of the projects, in which case the size will be much bigger indeed. Try to remove the vendor dir and then run `composer install --prefer-dist` to make sure you only get the package files and no git information. If it makes no difference though, I guess that's just the file size it is.

Another discrepancy might be due to the fact the zips on symfony.com have a lot of stuff removed from the vendor directory. Tests and documentation of vendors are stripped, while composer will not do that.

In any case though, it's just files. Disks are pretty cheap. I would not worry about it too much.

Comment: Thanks @seldaek for your help, now the size of the whole project is ~26MB

Comment: +1, but even if it is "just files", not only does it mean you need space, but also that you need many many inodes.

Comment: forget about the inode argument: it looks like the amount of inode used by a git repository is small, even for big repositories.

Comment: also for  regularly  backup of the files it makes sense to keep them small

Answer (score 0):

Some Node community has emberjs with 250mb right now...