# Symfony 6 project size

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony6

So I started learning symfony 6 a few days ago, the problem is that my projects are way too big, and I don't know if that's normal. I created a site with a single home page, and the project is still 120 MB, so my question is, is it normal or is it me, I'm doing it wrong?

To publish my project I put all the files on the server with ssh, except the vendor file and .gitignor , then on a terminal of the server I used the command: "Composer install" to install all the dependencies, and the I was surprised to see that the storage taken by my site is 120mb, I can't imagine if I had put images and lots of pages.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142684/231316

Comment: As nobody knows which packages you've installed, it's impossible to answer your question. Maybe you are also installing dev dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

the size of your project depends on what approach you take. Symfony as well as any other modern web framework supports both *monoliths* and *microservices* architecture. ( Since you started learning Symfony, I highly recommended looking more into this topic).
When you want to start a new Symfony project (using composer or Symfony CLI). You choose between two types of installation (by adding the keyword --webapp or without).
**with**:  you install the whole Symfony package(including things you need and things you don't need).
**without**: you only install the essential packages in order for your project to run